# what nodejs, react-native IP address has to be used in endpoint when app is in google play store?

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-play

So I made a react native app with nodeJS and in order to connect nodejs backend to react native frontend I had to create an endpoint like such:

```
app.post("/send_mail", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  let {text} = req.body
  var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
    port: 2525,
    auth: {
      user: "usertoken",
      pass: "password"
    }
  })
  await transport.sendMail({
    from: "email@email.com",
    to: "email2@email.com",
    subject: "message",
    html: `<p>${text}</p>`
  })
})
```

and in react native frontend call function like that :

```
const handleSend = async() => {
    try {
      await axios.post("http://192.168.0.104:3333/send_mail", {    //localhost
        text: placeHolderLocationLatLon
      })
    } catch (error) {
      setHandleSetError(error)
    }}
```

and it works fine in the local environment. But in the google play store, this IP address doesn't work because it's my localhost ipv4. I tried to use localhost:3333, but that doesn't work too. I can't find anywhere described anything about what IP has to be used in the google play store. Does anyone know how I should make this endpoint? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't just host a service by yourself like that (typically your back-end).  Well, you *can* but not with your knowledge level. It would be inefficient (as in you'd have to keep your computer up 24/7) and present security issues.

> Does anyone know how I should make this endpoint?

Don't get me wrong, your endpoint is **fine** in itself. You're just lacking the networking part.

### 1) For testing purposes ONLY!

If this app is only for testing purposes on your end, and won't be part of a final product that'll be present on the Google Store, there's a way you can achieve this, called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

It takes your locally-running project and provides it a https URL anyone can use to access it. I'll let you read the docs to find out how it works.

### 2) A somewhat viable solution (be extremely careful)

Since `ngrok` will provide a **new** URL everytime you run it with your local project, it's not very reliable in the long term.

What you could do, *if you have a static IP address*, is registering a domain name and link it to your IP address, and do all the shenanigans behind it (figuring out how to proxy incoming traffic to your machine and project, and so on). But honestly, it's way too cumbersome and it implies that you have valuable knowledge when it comes to securing your own private network, which I doubt.

### 3) A long-lasting, viable solution

You could loan a preemptive machine on [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/gcp/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-fr-all-fr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-gcp-1011340&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_529432261643-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20BKWS%20-%20EXA%20%7C%20Txt%20%7E%20GCP%20%7E%20General%23v2-KWID_43700060384861687-kwd-87853815-userloc_9055247&utm_term=KW_gcp-NET_g-PLAC_&gclid=Cj0KCQiA3rKQBhCNARIsACUEW_aoYfq8XJQ3NOL-Jih0n0gA8yrp9YOYnYCfInXLa_6JkA5L6WFOdx4aAiMDEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) and run your back-end service on it. Of course, you would still have to figure out some networking things and configs, but it's way more reliable than solution 2 and 1 if your whole app aims to be public.

Google gives you free credit (I think it's like 200 or 250€, can't recall exactly) to begin with their stuff, and running a preemptive machine is really cheap.